# How to create html to Pdf using ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I want to create a PDF file from my ASP.NET (HTML+CSS) but I positioning DIVs with CSS into a gridview  and I tried many .Dll like:-iTextSharp.dll  and no one could make me 100% same as HTML. but i failed . is there any way to convert html to pdf . or any free API. Please help me for these.....

Comment: You added WkHtmlToPdf as a tag, have you tried this tool?

Answer (score 0):

These sort of conversions are very tricky. I'd say wkhtmltopdf and PrinceXML are the best tools out there at the moment, but it depends a lot on the content and requirements. There is no one clear answer for this question as the best solution depends on your situation.

Search for a bunch of them, research each and every one, examine your requirements and stick with one.

Answer (score 0):

ABCpdf .NET provides real world web page conversion involving complex elements such as SVG, JavaScript, CSS, AJAX etc.

It includes two conversion engines - an MSHTML one for IE-like conversion and a Gecko one for FireFox-like conversion.

We get a lot of clients coming to us after trying other solutions. It works very well. But then I work on it so I would say that. ;-)